# Find the optimal linear combination of the following estimating function / quasi-score

Tags: mathematical-statistics, quasi-likelihood

Consider a random variable $Y_1 \sim Bin(n,\theta)$ and $Y_2 \sim Bin(n,\theta^2)$ where $Y_1$ is independent from $Y_2$.

Consider the residuals $R_1 = Y_1 - n\theta$ and $R_2 = Y_2 - n\theta^2$. Find the optimal linear combination of $R_1$ and $R_2$ for estimating $\theta$. Denote the resulting estimator by $\hat{\theta_n}$.

Attempt: Now my attempt at this problem was to consider the general quasi-score equation given by

$ \sum_{i=1}^n[\frac{\mu_i}{\beta}]^T [Var(y_i)]^{-1} (y_i - \mu_i)$

However, there is no $\beta$ link given in this problem so the derivative with respect to $\beta$ is just 1. I think we have to represent $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ as a summation of independent bernoullis with probabilities $\theta$ and $\theta^2$. I am not sure how to find the optimal linear combinations for $\alpha_1 R_1 + \alpha_2 R_2$ which is needed to construct the estimator $\hat{\theta}_n$.

Comment: How can $R_1$ and $R_2$ be used to estimate $\theta$ since they depend on $\theta$?  You could perhaps obtain an estimate based on a linear combination of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, but it is difficult to obtain an unbiased estimate of $\theta$ with such a set-up.  Additionally, it is worthwhile to note that the MLE of $\theta$ can be obtained in closed-form for this problem set-up

Comment: This is a question from a previous exam in grad school. Such an estimate based on the MLE is possible when we have $\frac{Y_1}{n}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{Y_2}{n}}$. In such a case the optimal linear combination has a constraint that $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 = 1$ and one can solve for them. However the questions specifically asks to construct an estimator based on the residuals $R_1$ and $R_2$ not on $Y_1$ and $Y_2$